# 'Code signing failed with error code 1'

Tags: iphone, ios, monodevelop, signing

I have a distribution provision I've enabled and I'm trying to compile my app for distribution. I'm getting the error that 'Code signing failed with error code 1' and it tells me to check my compiler output for details:

> codesign -v -f -s "iPhone
>   Distribution: Ahmed Hakeem"
>   "--resource-rules=/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/iOS/MyCode/MeteorMania/bin/iPhone/iPhoneDist/MeteorMania-MonoTouch.app/ResourceRules.plist"
>   --entitlements "/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/iOS/MyCode/MeteorMania/bin/iPhone/iPhoneDist/MeteorMania.xcent"
>   "/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/iOS/MyCode/MeteorMania/bin/iPhone/iPhoneDist/MeteorMania-MonoTouch.app"
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/iOS/MyCode/MeteorMania/bin/iPhone/iPhoneDist/MeteorMania-MonoTouch.app:
>   object file format invalid or
>   unsuitable
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/iOS/MyCode/MeteorMania/bin/iPhone/iPhoneDist/MeteorMania-MonoTouch.app:
>   object file format invalid or
>   unsuitable

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was being caused by the fact I had info.plists properties set to 'copy if newer' and 'content', after making it 'none' and 'never copy' the project compiled fine.